# Adding Color Maps to images in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, colormap

This is a fairly entry-level question but I could not find the answer to it here on SO or on Mathworks help.

I want to add a color bar to an image I am loading and then save the image along with the created color bar.

The result I am looking for is like figure 1 on [this page](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorbar.html) except that there is an image instead of the plot and the color bar shows the range of intensities in the image.

The page made me think that running

```
colorbar(<trarget matrix>);
```

Would do the trick but that throws an error when I try to apply it to an image.

**So my question is, how do I make a color bar for my image and once made what would be a good way to concatenate the two for saving.**

I am loading the image using the following snippet

```
IMGpath = 'barbaraSmall.png';
im = imread(IMGpath, 'png');
%
%colorbar(im); >>Throws an error
imshow(im);
imwrite(im, 'barabara_withMAP.png', 'png');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax that you're using is [`colorbar(target)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorbar.html). According to the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorbar.html#bt5djl2-1-target),
`target` is:

> "Target for the colorbar, specified as an Axes object, a PolarAxes object, or a graphics object that has a ColorbarVisible property".

You're inputting an image matrix (`im`) as `target` which is none of the above mentioned objects. You can simply just enter:

```
colorbar;
```

or if you want to give an axes' handle then:

```
colorbar(gca);
```

---

You can save the result using [`saveas`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html).

```
saveas(gca, 'barabara_withMAP.png')
```

Comment: The result I get on using the gca option is a stand-alone generic color map (unrelated to the image). Also, the command does not link it to the image in question at any stage nor does it operate on the image to extract a color map.

Comment: @ijuneja It *does* link with it.  If you doubt it, try with a grayscale image. i.e `im=rgb2gray(imread(IMGpath, 'png'));` you'll see

Comment: I may be doing it wrong. I am new to MATLAB and as I see it gca is a graphing option that links an object to an axis (Correct me!). In the sequence this is not invoking im anywhere

Comment: @ijuneja `gca` returns the handle of the current axes on which you showed `im`. And that's how it's related to `im`

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience. Accepted answer.

Comment: Is there a way to control how thick the white padding gets. In other words, how can we control the dimensions of the new image? I would appreciate if you add this to your answer.

Comment: @ijuneja `saveas` is saving what is being displayed on the figure. If you change the figure size before calling `saveas`, the saved figure will be according to the new figure size. To do this  programatically , read this( [Save Figure at Specific Size and Resolution](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/save-figure-at-specific-size-and-resolution.html) ) documentation page where it is explained with examples

Comment: Consider answering another question I had if you have the time. https://stackoverflow.com/q/51692593/3642162