# Prevent Color Bar from Resizing Image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure, colorbar

I am trying to add color bars to an image in MATLAB without losing the original resolution of the figure.

[This link](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/30986-avoid-colorbar-resizing-image) explains how to deal with the fact that adding a color bar resizes the original image. But the solution makes the original loose information by enlarging using interpolation (the `set` method used in the 6th line from the bottom). It is crucial to my application that this does not happen (Trying to observe Moire effects on sub-sampling)

The code I am using is appended below

```
%% Load images using relative paths
path1 = '../data/circles_concentric.png';
path2 = '../data/barbaraSmall.png';
img1 = imread(path1, 'png');
img2 = imread(path2, 'png');
%Shrinking factor
d1 = 2;
d2 = 3;
img1_shrunk1 = myShrinkImageByFactorD(img1, d1);
imshow(img1_shrunk1);
colorbar(gca); 
img1_shrunk2 = myShrinkImageByFactorD(img1, d2);
figure, imshow(img1_shrunk2);
colorbar(gca);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have dealt with this problem by simply putting the colorbar in a separate axis.

```
%Import image and colormap
[img,map]=imread('image.tif');

%Create figure and show the image on ax1
fig=figure;
ax1=axes(fig);
imshow(img,map,'Parent',ax1);

%Create ax2 and make it invisible
ax2=axes(fig,...
    'Position',[ax1.Position(1)+ax1.Position(3),ax1.Position(2),0.2,0.7]);
axis off
set(ax2,'color','none');

%Apply colormap to ax2 and, colorbar and adjust CLim
colormap(map);
colorbar(ax2,'Position',...
    [ax1.Position(1)+ax1.Position(3)+0.03,0.1,0.05,0.7],...
        'AxisLocation','in');
ax2.CLim=[minValue,maxValue];
```